# Android Comparison method violates its general contract with TalkBack

Tags: android, exception, mergesort, comparable, talkback

With app TalkBack active, I receive the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
```

The problem is I'm not using comparision method on my code.
Follow the complete exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
                                                       at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeLo(ComparableTimSort.java:710)
                                                       at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeAt(ComparableTimSort.java:447)
                                                       at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeCollapse(ComparableTimSort.java:372)
                                                       at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:178)
                                                       at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:142)
                                                       at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1970)
                                                       at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1864)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup$ChildListForAccessibility.init(ViewGroup.java:6635)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup$ChildListForAccessibility.obtain(ViewGroup.java:6600)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.addChildrenForAccessibility(ViewGroup.java:1703)
                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(ViewGroup.java:2529)
                                                       at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:5225)
                                                       at android.widget.AdapterView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AdapterView.java:937)
                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AbsListView.java:1494)
                                                       at android.widget.GridView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(GridView.java:2263)
                                                       at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(View.java:5186)
                                                       at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:5173)
                                                       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:811)
                                                       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:834)
                                                       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchAccessibilityNodeInfos(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:720)
                                                       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.findAccessibilityNodeInfoByAccessibilityIdUiThread(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:147)
                                                       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.access$300(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:49)
                                                       at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:971)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Why I've this exception only with TalkBack active? This exception appear after that gridview is loaded (on display the gridview is loaded correctly)

Thanks a lot

EDIT:

I've found that the problem is on this code line:

```
public class GridLayoutAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

       view.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(60, 60));
}
```

How to resolve the problem? I don't know why I've a Comparison method violates
(if I try to comment the line it works without crash)

Comment: Did you ever solve this?